# WPF Thread Delay

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, task

I have a method which I call in a new task with

```
// get the dispatcher for the UI thread
var uiDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => BackgroundThreadProc(uiDispatcher));
```

In the method `BackgroundThreadProc()` I need a delay of few seconds. I tried it with the DispatcherTimer and the task.delay function but it didn't work. The only thing which worked was the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)` but I think the `Thread.Sleep()` function isn't the best solution.

This is my function:

```
public void BackgroundThreadProc(Dispatcher uiDispatcher)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var task = Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // create object
            var animal = new Animal { Name = "test" + i };
            uiDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => log(animal)));
        });
    }
}
```

As I found out it didn't work because the DispatcherTimer is running in the UI thread. How I can accomplish the delay in the function which is in a other thread than the UI thread?

**Update:**

Now I tried it with the timer:

```
   public void BackgroundThreadProc(Dispatcher uiDispatcher)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var _delayTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            _delayTimer.Interval = 1000;
            //_delayTimer.Enabled = true;
            _delayTimer.Elapsed += delegate
            {
                var animal = new Animal { Name = "test" + i };
                uiDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => log(animal)));
                _delayTimer.Stop();
            };
            _delayTimer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Task.Delay` to introduce a delay asynchrnoously:

```
var task = Task.Delay(1000)
    .ContinueWith(t => BackgroundThreadProc());
```

Comment: Hy, thank you for ypur answer. I tried it with your example but the problem is after the delay ends it alway writes "test100" to my output because after the delay the for loop is already fineshed but I want after every i++ a delay. I added the BackgroundThreadProc() to my post.

Comment: @user2644964 Sounds like you just want a `Timer`.  You can do this using the TPL, but it's way more work than it's worth.  Just use a `Timer`.

Comment: Hy, with timer you meant the System.Timers.Timer? I tried a example and updated the main post under "Update" you can find the function I tried. I have the same problem there in the end it writes only a houndret times "test100" on the output.

Comment: @user2644964 You don't want to create 100 timers, you want to create *one* timer and let it fire 100 times.

Answer (score 1):

Are you limited to C# 4.0? I assume you're not, because `Task.Delay` wouldn't be available.

So, make `BackgroundThreadProc` an `async` method and use `await` inside it:

```
// get the dispatcher for the UI thread
var uiDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
var task = BackgroundThreadProc(uiDispatcher));

// ...

public async Task BackgroundThreadProc(Dispatcher uiDispatcher)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // create object
        var animal = new Animal { Name = "test" + i };
        uiDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => log(animal)));
    }
}
```

You really don't need `Task.Factory.StartNew` here, the execution will continue on thread pool after `await Task.Delay`.

Apparently, you're only updating the UI from this `BackgroundThreadProc`. If that's the case, just remove `ConfigureAwait(false)` and don't use `uiDispatcher.Invoke`:

```
public async Task BackgroundThreadProc()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        // create object
        var animal = new Animal { Name = "test" + i };
        log(animal);
    }
}
```

This loop will be executing asynchronously on the WPF UI thread.

Otherwise, if you do have any other CPU-bound work *before* `Task.Delay`, then you may need `Task.Factory.StartNew` to avoid freezing the UI (note `Unwrap`):

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    BackgroundThreadProc(uiDispatcher)).Unwrap();
```

You can also use `Task.Run`, which unwraps the inner task automatically:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => BackgroundThreadProc(uiDispatcher));
```