# Constant loop - Thread vs Async, best practice

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have some common code that i seem to use often when it comes to some of our in house applications.

```
public State SomeState { get; set; }
Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadProc)
thread.Start();

void ThreadProc() {
    while(isTrue){
       //Changes SomeState after ping
       //Can take up to 5 seconds to complete if service is unavailable
       PingServiceTocheckState(); 
       UpdateUI();
       Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}

void UpdateUI() {

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(UpdateUI));
        return;
    }

    if(SomeState == State.Up){
        //set these UI values (txt.Text = ...)
    }
    ......
}
```

And the constant action may be updating Ui on a windows form or constantly reading from a network stream.

I feel this is probably outdated when compared to TPL and Async.

Am I correct to feel it can be better managed using Async/TPL?
And if so, could someone give me an example of how i would accomplish the above using these new ideas?

*Note: I currently use async occasionally and I am trying to make it more prevalent in my coding, but I am a little lost on the best method for creating a longrunning "background thread" using async.

**Edit:**

I have updated my example with a little more detail relating to my current project. I have code similar to this in a UserControl. I then have a windows form which adds ~50 of these controls dynamically. Without the Thread the form basically hangs, with the thread everything runs smooth. I just figured that rather than managing the thread myself async/TPL would manage the tasks (Ping and Update) more efficiently than myself.

Comment: Its not a good practice to update the UI from a worker thread, even for in-house applications. Make sure you are invoking everything!

Comment: Threads aren't replaced by tasks. Tasks are...tasks and they're executed with a thread from pool and I really really would avoid to use them for a while(condition) long running operation.

Comment: Does `PerformAction()` have to wait for IO?

Comment: You can run your loop asynchronously on the UI thread, if you don't do CPU-bound work inside it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22649807/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio isn't that just an overly complicated way of writing a UI timer control ;p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TPL is well suited to tasks that are short in duration - as you are basically using up workers from a pool. If your operation is continuous, a dedicated thread is entirely appropriate. If, however, the `PerformAction` is actually blocking waiting on data coming into a queue, and only actually has anything to do very briefly and occasionally, then yes: the TPL may come back into play. But then there is a question of sequential vs concurrent programming: at the moment, in that scenario, you will be processing things sequentially. The TPL makes no such guarantees, and is intended to process things concurrently. It is of course possible to write code that *uses* the TPL (or just the regualar `ThreadPool`) to process a sequential queue, but it is a bit more complicated, and there are edge-cases and thread-races around the "is there a current worker? do I need to start one? is it me?" questions.

Comment: Marc, can you explain how the TPL would come back into play for a case where `PerformAction` was blocking on a queue?

Comment: @DavidHaney as per the edit: that is pretty gnarly and has thread-races all around it; I have an example, though: [`ProcessAsyncCompletionQueueImpl`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/CompletionManager.cs#L114), basically, whoever wins: wins.

Comment: @DavidHaney I should clarify that that code is only ever invoked if the queue was empty when work came in

Comment: Marc - thanks for that. I see what you're saying. The joys of multiplexers and asynchronous multi-threaded code. :)

Comment: Marc- for what it's worth, I think that you could improve this code very slightly. The `asyncCompletionQueue.Count` property of the queue could be checked in a double-lock-check fashion vs within the lock itself. This would allow you to lock only when you potentially have some work to do, no? (This is very off topic haha).

Comment: @DavidHaney I'm not convinced that is a good idea; the result of `Count` isn't even *defined* when accessed by competing threads (writes vs reads - "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."). Then it gets into implementation questions like "when, during `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` does `Count` get incremented/decremented?" - and keep in mind that this code runs on both Mono and CLR. I don't think that would be a good change, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @DavidHaney besides which - locks are actually insanely cheap when not contested, and when they *are* contested: that is the exact scenario where I need it to be accurate

Comment: True enough, and valid points. I've never had an issue with `Count` checks, but my code doesn't have to be accurate in my case either. I usually just check "if there's work to do" in a loop or timer that sleeps between intervals, so if it's 0 now that doesn't really matter because when it's > 0 later I'll catch it.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread`, `TPL`, `Async` stand on shoulders of the same OS kernel objects and artifacts. They are just different classes that provide different functionality to you.

None of them provides you with true low level control over threading, but, for example `TPL`, *if can*, splits your task among different cores of your CPU, and finds in general best possible way of paralleling your task on multi-core modern processors, so tends to be faster and more lightweight.

So `TPL` is a suggested library for multi threading handling in your app, if you have and can use most updated .NET framework.